Fourier transform in weighted $L^p$ spaces
I'm studying the Fourier transform on a tempered distribution space. This operator is an isomorphism on tempered distribution space and any $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ can be identified with a tempered distribution $T_u(\phi)=\int u \phi$. This implies that $\hat{u}$ has sense (in a distributional sense) and if $\hat{u}=\hat{v}$ with $u,v\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $u=v$, identifying $u$ and $v$ with tempered distributions.
Now, if $u\in L_w^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $w$ a weight function (weighted $L^p$ space) then the functional  $T_{w,u}(\phi)=\int w^{1/p}u \phi$ is well defined (i.e. $\left|T_{w,u}\phi\right|_{\infty}<\infty$ for all $\phi$ Schwartz function).
Therefore, for any u$\in L_w^p$: Is $T_{w,u}$ a tempered distribution?
